# Perl equivalent of a pool of workers in Python

Tags: python, perl, multiprocessing

I have some Python code that does exactly what I want however I also have the need for something similar in Perl.

Here is the Python code I have:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
for item in list:
    pool.apply_async(myFunction, args=(item,))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

This code runs each function in it's own process rather than a thread. The maximum amount of processes that run at the same time is equal to the number of logical cores.

Comment: Have a look at [Thread::Pool](https://metacpan.org/pod/Thread::Pool)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new($MAX_PROCESSES);

foreach my $item (@list) {
    $pm->start and next;
    my_function($item);
    $pm->finish;
}
$pm->wait_all_children;
```